# Extract only the specific value from string with Regex Using Python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, regex-group, pypdf

I am trying to extract Specific text values from string using regex but due to not having the spaces between the start of the keyword from which the values need to be extracted getting the error.
Looking out to extract the values of the keywords starts with.

Tried using PyPDF2 and pdfminer but getting the Error.

```
fr = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
data = fr.getPage(0).extractText()
```

OutPut : ['Date : 2020-09-06 20:43:00**Ack No : 3320000266**Original for RecipientInvoice No.: IN05200125634**Date of Issue:** 06.09.2015TAX INVOICE(Issued u/s 31(1) of GST Act, 2017)POLO INDUSTRIES LIMITED**CIN: K253648B85PLC015063**GSTIN: 3451256132uuy668803E1Z9PAN: BBB7653279K  .....']

**I am looking out to capture Ack No, Date of Issue, CIN from the above output**

Using the script:

```
    regex_ack_no = re.compile(r"Ack No(\d+)")
    regex_due_date = re.compile(r"Date of Issue(\S+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})")
    regex_CIN = re.compile(r"CIN(\$\d+\.\d{1,2})")

ack_no = re.search(regex_ack_no, data).group(1)
due_date = re.search(regex_due_date, data).group(1)
cin = re.search(regex_CIN, data).group(1)

return[ack_no, due_date, cin]
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

When using the same script with the another PDF file having data in the table format its working.

Comment: You're not matching the `:` between `Ack No` and the number. You're not matching the `:` after `Date of Issue`. You're not matching the `:` after `CIN`, and the format of `CIN` is not `$` followed by a number with 1-2 decimal digits.

Comment: In other words, the regular expressions don't seem to match the data format at all.

Comment: @Barmar - Have tried using above methods as well that you mentioned but didn't worked, Now I am trying to match the keyword starts with Ack No, Date of Issue, CIN, as we have to capture values from multiple PDF.

Comment: Date of issue is `\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}`, why are you matching `\d{1,2}, \d{4}`?

Comment: Not getting the point , Can you please explain ?

Comment: How much clearer can I be? Your regular expressions don't seem to be related to the data format.

Comment: I'm trying to write an answer, but I don't know how to parse `CIN`. It looks like it runs into `GSTIN`, with no delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the regexp patterns to match the data format. The keywords are followed by spaces and `:`, you have to match them. The format of the date is not what you have in your pattern, neither is the format of `CIN`.

Before calling `.group(1)`, check that the match was successful. In my code below I return default values when there's no match.

```
import re

data = 'Date : 2020-09-06 20:43:00Ack No : 3320000266Original for RecipientInvoice No.: IN05200125634Date of Issue: 06.09.2015TAX INVOICE(Issued u/s 31(1) of GST Act, 2017)POLO INDUSTRIES LIMITEDCIN: K253648B85PLC015063GSTIN: 3451256132uuy668803E1Z9PAN: BBB7653279K .....'

regex_ack_no = re.compile(r"Ack No\s*:\s*(\d+)")
regex_due_date = re.compile(r"Date of Issue\s*:\s*(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})")
regex_CIN = re.compile(r"CIN:\s*(\w+?)GSTIN:")

ack_no = re.search(regex_ack_no, data)
if ack_no:
    ack_no = ack_no.group(1)
else:
    ack_no = 'Ack No not found'
due_date = re.search(regex_due_date, data)
if due_date:
    due_date = due_date.group(1)
else:
    due_date = 'Due date not found'
cin = re.search(regex_CIN, data)
if cin:
    cin = cin.group(1)
else:
    cin = 'CIN not found'

print([ack_no, due_date, cin])
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/1lJyMx)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer, As i am new to this language Just want to know ""regex_CIN = re.compile(r"CIN:\s*(\w+?)GSTIN:") , why we have used GSTIN in the regular expression, We have PDF in different structure format SO what will happen in the case where GSTIN is not present, so do we have to make the change in script, IS there a way to find CIN without using GSTIN in the regular expression.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, there's no delimiter after the `CIN` value, so I used `GSTIN:` to detect the end.

Comment: You could make `GSTIN` optional with `(?:GSTIN:)?`, but then it might include some other field in the CIN. Unless you can define straightforward rules for how to find the different bits, you're going to have a hard time with this.